# How do I turn a PD df into a multiindex?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that has adj close price for two symbols 'SPY' and 'JPM' in sym_df.
I want to create a multiindex df to be able to run tests on each symbol. At the moment I am doing it all on stock at a time but wont to do it all at once with pd multiindex df.

I know that pd Panels have been deprecated so I am looking for a different way to create a 3D df.

```
>>>print(sym_df)

          SPY    JPM
2010-01-04  108.27  40.87
2010-01-05  108.56  41.67
2010-01-06  108.64  41.89
2010-01-07  109.10  42.72
2010-01-08  109.46  42.62
...            ...    ...
2011-12-23  125.19  32.84
2011-12-27  125.29  32.31
2011-12-28  123.64  31.94
2011-12-29  124.92  32.69
2011-12-30  124.31  32.53

[504 rows x 2 columns]


>>>spy_df = pd.DataFrame({'Adj_Close_Price': sym_df['SPY']})
>>>data = {'SPY':spy_df}  
>>>sym_df = sym_df.drop(['SPY'], axis=1)
>>>sym_df = sym_df.rename(columns={symbol: 'Adj_Close_Price'})
>>>data[symbol] = sym_df
>>>print(data)

{'SPY':             Adj_Close_Price
2010-01-04           108.27
2010-01-05           108.56
2010-01-06           108.64
2010-01-07           109.10
2010-01-08           109.46
...                     ...
2011-12-23           125.19
2011-12-27           125.29
2011-12-28           123.64
2011-12-29           124.92
2011-12-30           124.31

[504 rows x 1 columns], 'JPM':             Adj_Close_Price
2010-01-04            40.87
2010-01-05            41.67
2010-01-06            41.89
2010-01-07            42.72
2010-01-08            42.62
...                     ...
2011-12-23            32.84
2011-12-27            32.31
2011-12-28            31.94
2011-12-29            32.69
2011-12-30            32.53

[504 rows x 1 columns]}

>>>df = pd.concat(data.values(), keys=data.keys())
>>>print(df)

                Adj_Close_Price
SPY 2010-01-04           108.27
    2010-01-05           108.56
    2010-01-06           108.64
    2010-01-07           109.10
    2010-01-08           109.46
...                         ...
JPM 2011-12-23            32.84
    2011-12-27            32.31
    2011-12-28            31.94
    2011-12-29            32.69
    2011-12-30            32.53

[1008 rows x 1 columns]

>>>print(type(df))

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Comment: Try: `df.unstack()`.

Comment: No, it turned my df into a [2 rows x 504 Columns] shape. I am looking for exactly what I have but when I do df.loc('SPY'), I get a `ValueError: No axis named SPY for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

Comment: works great on my side: `df = syn_df.unstack().to_frame(name='Adj_Close_Price')` then `df.loc['SPY']` gives essentially `sym_df['SPY']`.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Have you consulted the [Advanced Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html) section of the Pandas user guide? Also, please provide the data in a more convenient format.

Answer (score 0):

You used the round brackets `()` instead of the square brackets `[]`. Also what you did can be shortened into a single command:

```
df = sym_df.unstack().to_frame('Adj_Close_Price')
df.loc['SPY']
```

Result:

```
            Adj_Close_Price
2010-01-04           108.27
2010-01-05           108.56
2010-01-06           108.64
2010-01-07           109.10
2010-01-08           109.46
2011-12-23           125.19
2011-12-27           125.29
2011-12-28           123.64
2011-12-29           124.92
2011-12-30           124.31
```